# How do I display an annotation using the Users current location when a button is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, gps, annotations, mapkit

So I am creating an app that when a button is clicked, the users current location is used to create an annotation on Apples mapkit. I have everything working except for linking the button up to code that will create the annotation and display the annotation on the map. Bellow is the code I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {

    println("Updating Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) , \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) ")

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0009, 0.0009)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, span: span)
    Map.setRegion(region, animated: false)
    }
}
```

As you will see, I have it so it constantly shows the user where they are. I want this but I also want the user to be able to create the annotation.

My question is what code do I need to create the annotations and where does it go? I am fairly new to programing so I'm not completely comprehensive of all of the code lingo so if you would (dumb things down for me please). Also, when the user clicks the button that adds the annotation, the last annotation needs to be deleted. How would I do this? I am using Swift in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

- First, create an annotation at the top of the code (just within the class):

  `var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()`
- Then, use `newLocation.coordinate.latitude` and `.longitude` to create a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and set that to `annotation.coordinate`.

  - Then use `map.title = "something"` and `map.addAnnotation(annotation)`.
  - You'll need to have some of the variables more global to achieve this, but before you place the annotation, simply use `map.removeAnnotation(annotation)` - so you only ever have one annotation on the screen at a time.

Comment: Ok, so here is what I have:

Comment: import UIKit
    import CoreLocation
    import MapKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    //new code added
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    //
    @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
    }

Comment: override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        println("Updating Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) , \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) ")
        //new code added
        newLocation.coordinate.latitude
        newLocation.coordinate.longitude
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0009, 0.0009)

Comment: let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, span: span)
        Map.setRegion(region, animated: false)
    }
}

Comment: OK so that code centers the map on the user's location constantly. To set an annotation first set a class-wide variable called currentLocation of type CLLocation and in the didUpdateToLocation method set currentLocation to new location.

Comment: When the button is pressed : use currentLocation.coordinate.latitude and longitude to set up a CLLocationCoordinate2D called annotationLocation. Set that to annotation.coordinate. Then add the annotation as I show in the answer

Comment: In order to remove the previous annotation and so only have one at a time, check at the top of the button action code if annotation != nil. If yes, then use map.removeAnnotation(annotation) to remove the previous one. If no, then it must be the first pin placed so there is nothing to remove! Hope this helps!

Comment: I really appreciate all you have done so far for me but like I said in my post "I am fairly new to programing so I'm not completely comprehensive..." I really liked the way you had things in your fist Answer. It helped me visualize things. I think I have everything up to the second bullet in you original answer. Correct me if I'm wrong.